# Callback function when function is done in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this function in angular

```
 $rootScope.openMobileUpdateModal = function () {
   ......something.......
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'mobileModal.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
      });
    };
```

and I need function that will be called when this function is done (when modal is opened and elements are created). How to create callback on this function?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `opened` parameter to open method. `opened` is a promise, that will be resolved, when modal window will open.

```
$rootScope.openMobileUpdateModal = function () {
  ......something.......
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'mobileModal.html',
    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
    opened: // Your Promise object here
  });
};
```

Comment: What is promise object?

Comment: @user3433459 please look AngularJS documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
http://www.promisejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass a function to the opened promisse...

```
$rootScope.openMobileUpdateModal = function () {
  ......something.......
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'mobileModal.html',
    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
  });

  modalInstance.opened.then(function () {
// The modal is opened and the elements are created
  });
```

};